# How many ways are there of distributing the bottles if nobody has two (or more) bottles more than anybody else?

Tags: combinatorics

The student rugby team has $15$ members, and after their match they
share two identical crates of beer, each containing $24$ bottles.

(c) How many ways are there if nobody has two (or more) bottles more than anybody else?

For C)  My answer is $15$ choose $3$. Since if there is one member who has at $3$ bottles then the remaining $14$ members get $45$ distributable bottles. In which case the only possible way under the restrictions above is to have all $14$ members to have each $3$ bottles of beer so the remaining $45 -3\times14=3$ bottles to distribute between the $15$ members which leads me to the answer above. It doesn't work if there is a person with $2$ beers since then it means some people will need to have $4$ beers. It also does not work for any member to have $5$ or above for the same reason.

(d) How many ways are there if instead there is one crate of beer and one crate of cider?

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry I'm on mobile so it's a bit hard to write. I edited a bit now for my answer for part c but didn't figure out d) yet. I'll try to maybe rewrite it again tomorrow on my computer

Comment: Does every member have to get at least one bottle ?

Comment: @trueblueanil not necessarily. every bottle needs to be distributed so say there are no leftovers. You could have 1 member with all the bottles and everyone else 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the students are distinguishable, and that bottles with equal content are indistinguishable.

You have correctly solved problem (c). But problem (d) is much more complicated. We can still choose the $3$ students receiving $4$ bottles in ${15\choose3}=455$ ways. Assume that these students have been chosen. We now distribute the bottles of beer in an arbitrary way such that no student gets more than his total allowance. Then we hand out the bottles of cider so that each student has his due number of bottles in total.

The number of ways to distribute the beer bottles is the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in the product
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3\ (1+x+x^2+x^3)^{12}=(1-x^5)^3(1-x^4)^{12}(1-x)^{-15}\ .$$
The right hand side is needed if you want to compute this coefficient by hand (you obtain a messy binomial sum). I have used Mathematica, and obtained $180\,431\,304$. Multiply this with $455$ to obtain the final result.